# Clear method is unclear when implementing stacks in JS

Tags: javascript, data-structures, stack

I was recently looking at this book [chapter](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/data-structures-and/9781449373931/ch04.html), which explained how to create stacks in JS. This is the code:

```
function Stack() {
   this.dataStore = [];
   this.top = 0;
   this.push = push;
   this.pop = pop;
   this.peek = peek;
   this.clear = clear;
   this.length = length;
}

function push(element) {
   this.dataStore[this.top++] = element;
}

function peek() {
   return this.dataStore[this.top-1];
}

function pop() {
   return this.dataStore[--this.top];
}

function clear() {
   this.top = 0;
}

function length() {
   return this.top;
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding the `clear()` method. Why does setting the `top` to 0 clear the array? I was also expecting the line `this.dataStore.length = 0`. It seems like setting the `top` to 0 only changes the pointer and the dataStore is unchanged, meaning that further operations would just overwrite the previous dataStore values. Can anyone explain what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: It just overwrites from 0. Doesn't clear the elements in the array.

Comment: These functions should all be methods on the Stack prototype.  This code as you show it here will not work.

Comment: Yeah, I just copied and pasted the code from the book. I think this sample code was for demonstration purposes or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems like setting the top to 0 only changes the pointer and the
>   `dataStore` is unchanged, meaning that further operations would just
>   overwrite the previous `dataStore` values.

You are absolutely right. And I agree this behavior may be undesirable.

Instead, I suggest the following:

```js
function Stack() {
   this.dataStore = [];
}
Object.assign(Stack.prototype, {
  push: function(element) {
    this.dataStore.push(element);
  },
  peek: function() {
    return this.dataStore[this.dataStore.length-1];
  },
  pop: function() {
    return this.dataStore.pop();
  },
  clear: function() {
    this.dataStore.length = 0;
  },
  length: function() {
    return this.dataStore.length;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Data store isn't cleared because it is not necessary. While you are using this stack object, you don't need to work with `dataStore` directly, only via functions of `Stack` object.

So you can remain `dataStore` unchanged, it allows you to do same work with less operation and maybe faster.